# Opera 16.0 passwords saved location?

Tags: passwords, save, opera, wand

Old version of Opera web browser's password is saving in this file 'Wand.dat' but the v of 16.0 location has changed & cannot find the 'Wand.dat' file.In under which file the password is saving?

**OLD**:

```
C:\users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Opera\Opera\profile\wand.dat
```

**NEW**:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\
```

There is no WAND.DAT file in new version. So what is the new file name and the location of the file?

Answer (score 3):

file is

**Login Data**

in

> C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\